# How to emulate keys through ssh / NMSSH

Tags: swift, xcode, ssh, nmssh

I'm looking for some help on how to simulate keys through strings / SSH. I've been using the SSH Framework NMSSH. I've got sending all the commands working through the channel.write command except one. I need to send the command Ctrl + C to abort out of something. Any idea's on how to do this? I'm not sure how to send a "Key" along with the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is the character at [codepoint 3](https://unicode-table.com/en/0003/). It's formally known as ETX (end of text), and it's part of the ["control character" block](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/control-character/). It's a non-printing character, so you have to express it using a special character sequence. I'm not a swift programmer, but it looks like you'd specify it like this:

```
let ctrlC: Character = "\u{3}"
```